# insert array in radiobutton. 0 for false answer and 1 for correct answer

Tags: mysql, arrays, radio-button

Im having trouble with radio buttons, I dont have idea to insert the value which have correct answer. if selected the value must be 1 while the other is 0. this is my code :

```
    <form method='post' action='exam.php?act=input' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<table>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
    <td>Nama Exam </td>
    <td><input type='text' name='nama_exam'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Soal </td>
    <td><textarea name='soal_exam'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='answer'> <textarea name='option[]'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='answer'> <textarea name='option[]'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='answer'> <textarea name='option[]'></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='answer'> <textarea name='option[]'></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

and this is the insert code :

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['nama_exam'];
$exam = $_POST['soal_exam'];
$op = $_POST['option'];
$answer = $_POST['answer'];
//if selected = 1 else = 0

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `exam`(`exam_name`, `exam`, `exam_entrydate`) VALUES ('$name','$exam',NOW())");
if ($sql){
$v_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exam order by exam_id DESC limit 1");
    $id = mysql_fetch_array($v_soal);
    $id_soal = $id['exam_id'];
    $pil = count($op);
    for($i=0; $i<$pil; $i++){
    $sql_pil = mysql_query("INSERT INTO answer (`answer_examcode`,`answer`, `answer_code`,`answer_entrydate`) values ('$id_soal','$op[$i]','$answer',NOW())");
}
echo"
  <script language='javascript'>
          alert('Data ditambahkan')
          document.location='exam.php?act=default'
         </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use looping at your post form to post array to insert code file :

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=4; $i++){
echo "<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='radio' value='$i' name='answer'> <textarea name='option[$i]'></textarea></td>
</tr>";
}
?>
```

then you get array in insert code file like this :

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['nama_exam'];
$exam = $_POST['soal_exam'];

$op = $_POST['option'];
$answer = $_POST['answer'];

foreach($op as $i=>$op){
if($answer==$i){

$ans=1;
}else{
$ans=0;
}
$sql_pil = mysql_query("INSERT INTO answer (`answer_examcode`,`answer`, `answer_code`,`answer_entrydate`) values ('$id_soal','$op','$ans',NOW())");
}

?>
```